# Beautiful Soup Python - How to Handle Multiple Attribute Names?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website that has various attribute names for images I want to get. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to get the attribute that I want. I don't control the website, so I can't make any changes there, it has to be done on my side of things.

I  can get all the images that I want easily:

```
imgs = soup.find_all('img' : {'class' : 'slide-img'})
```

And it returns them something like this:

```
<img **src**="https://www.website.com/mydog.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my dog.">
<img **data-src**="https://www.website.com/mycat.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my cat.">
<img **href**="https://www.website.com/myfish.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my fish.">
<img **lazy-src**="https://www.website.com/mymouse.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my mouse.">
```

I'm trying to get the full size images for each one. What I'm doing now is ugly and I'm wondering if there's a better solution to my problem.

My current solution is just an ugly series of try statements....

```
try:
    img = url['data-src']
    return img[:img.find('?')]
except:
    img = ''

try:
    img = url['src']
    return img[:img.find('?')]
except:
    img = ''

try:
    img = url['lazy-src']
    return img[:img.find('?')]
except:
    img = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Define a list of image attributes, and check whether the HTML tag's attribute is within the list:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
_attributes = ['src', 'data-src', 'href', 'lazy-src']

out = []

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    for attr in _attributes:
        if attr in img.attrs:
            out.append(img.attrs[attr])
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('No valid attribute found')

print(out)
```

---

Complete runnable example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """ \
<img src="https://www.website.com/mydog.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my dog.">
<img data-src="https://www.website.com/mycat.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my cat.">
<img href="https://www.website.com/myfish.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my fish.">
<img lazy-src="https://www.website.com/mymouse.jpg?sw=200&amp;sh=200&amp;sm=fit" alt="A photo of my mouse.">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
_attributes = ['src', 'data-src', 'href', 'lazy-src']

out = []

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    for attr in _attributes:
        if attr in img.attrs:
            out.append(img.attrs[attr])
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('No valid attribute found')

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['https://www.website.com/mydog.jpg?sw=200&sh=200&sm=fit', 'https://www.website.com/mycat.jpg?sw=200&sh=200&sm=fit', 'https://www.website.com/myfish.jpg?sw=200&sh=200&sm=fit', 'https://www.website.com/mymouse.jpg?sw=200&sh=200&sm=fit']
```